# SAS macros to save and list all macros in a session

Tags: macros, sas

I would like to save all the macros permanently defined as part of an exercise and list all the macros. I have 6 macros which I want to save and retrieve in this session:

```
%macro one(a,b,c)
%macro gchart(dseti,Weight,Gender)
%macro plot(dsetin,height,weight)
%macro one(a,b,c,strtpt,endpt)
%macro test
%macro name(dsetin,year,revenue)
%macro import_myfile(i=)
```

I have the code below and the error message follows it.

```
options mstored sasmstore=macross; 
libname mjstore "C:\Users\komal\Desktop\Advanced SAS"; 
 proc catalog cat=mjstore.macross;
      contents;
      title "Default Storage of SAS Macros";
     quit

Error: Catalog "MJSTORE.MACROSS" not found
```

Please let me know your advice on how to solve it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you clarify the question?  Are you trying to tell which macros were DEFINED during the program? Or actually executed during the program?

Comment: yes the macros above were actually defined and executed in the program.

Answer (score 0):

The default catalog is WORK.SASMACR

```
%macro one(a,b,c); %mend;
%macro gchart(dseti,Weight,Gender); %mend;
%macro plot(dsetin,height,weight); %mend;
%macro one(a,b,c,strtpt,endpt); %mend;
%macro test; %mend;
%macro name(dsetin,year,revenue); %mend;
%macro import_myfile(i=); %mend;

proc catalog cat=work.SASMACR;
   contents;
   title "Default Storage of SAS Macros";
   quit;
```

Comment: Thanks. When creating the macros, I have used %mend after defining the macro.                                                                                                          Can I use "options mstored sasmstore"  to save all these macros created before in this session?                                                                    Is it possible to save the macros in a new library and then list all the macros using proc catalog?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out which macros were defined during your program is to not use stored macro catalog options. Instead just let SAS default to storing them a WORK catalog.  You can then use PROC CATALOG to see what macros have been compiled.  Normally that will be WORK.SASMACR catalog, but if you are using alternative ways of running SAS (Enterprise Guide, SAS/Studio, stored process servers etc) it might be WORK.SASMACR1 catalog instead.

```
proc print data= sashelp.vcatalg width=min;
  where libname='WORK' and memname='SASMACR'
    and memtype='CATALOG' and objtype='MACRO'
  ;
  var objname modified objdesc ;
run;
```

If you are using autocall macros newer versions of SAS will store the filename in the OBJDESC field in the metadata.  Otherwise here is a link to a macro that will generate a list of the compiled macros and try to match them to a corresponding source file from the autocall library or other directories you might provide it.  https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/maclist.sas